# Optimizing search query

Tags: mysql, search, optimization, query-optimization

This might seem to be a redundant question but i can't find the right answer to this issue.
I have a TableA with more than 50 columns.I am implementing a search functionality for searching a query in about 10 columns of this table. TableA contains more than a million rows
For this I have created a composite index on these 10 columns.
`index (col1,col_2,col_3,col_4,col_5,col_6,col_7,col_8,col_9,col_10)`
Now i am splitting user's query using space as regex. i.e. 
`$search_words = $search_query.split(' ');` 
and using individual words to match in my search query. Example :

```
SELECT something FROM tableA 
WHERE ( MATCH ( col_1, col_2,col_3,col_4,col_5,col_6,col_7,col_8,col_9,col_10 )
AGAINST ( ' +word1* +word2* +word3* +word4* ' IN BOOLEAN MODE ) )
```

This query works fine for general searches but if users searches for individual alphabets in query like *A E I O Co.* it takes too much time. What is the best way to optimise the query or another way to perform search in this situation?

Comment: E.g. Dont let them search single chars for myisam fulltext search. Adjust `ft_min_word_len` to 2 so it will perform better fulltext searching. If you really need that happen, then you should consider using a search engine such as `sphinxse` or `elasticsearch.`. Mysql cant handle it very well.

Comment: make minimum symbols count in code.
why dont u split data to other table.
are u realy need to hold all these in a lot of columns.

I would create table with 3 columns

id,pointer_to_item_or_product,search_word

are u need somekind of sequence in search?

Comment: @abeyaz can't restrict search as it can be a valid search and am not allowed to  use search engine such as lucene, elasticsearch etc. right now as it will be implemented after some time. But till that have to improve this functionality.

Comment: Then you should follow the advise from @MatasLesinskas

Comment: As you already realized, a mysql fulltext search is very useful to find rare words, but gets less effective up to unusable if your query will return a large portion of your table. One choice could be to not use a fulltext search, at least in edge cases (e.g. if the input contains 1-letter search terms or words you know are "slow"). Or only for columns that actually can contain more than 1 word (if at all, and you not just want a shortcut for "compare all columns to all terms"). Or matas wordlist. Without details about your data/search terms/table sizes, it's hard to be more concrete though.

Comment: That had better be a `FULLTEXT` index on those 10 columns.  A plain `INDEX` won't work with `MATCH`.

Comment: Is this MyISAM?  Or InnoDB?  It makes a big difference.

Comment: @RickJames it is a `FULLTEXT` index and InnoDB

Answer (score 0):

If you feed a too-short string to InnoDB's FULLTEXT, it returns zero results.  So...  Filter out any strings that are shorter than `innodb_ft_min_token_size`.

If necessary, test for them separately using `REGEXP '[[:<:]]A[[:>:]]` to look for a 1-letter word `A`.

Or throw them together.  This would check for the only 1-letter English words:  `REGEXP '[[:<:]][AI][[:>:]]`